# how can I change the interface ip address in linux without ifconfig command. my current interface and want to change the ip to 192.168.10.100

Tags: linux, interface

```
network:
 version:2 
renderer :
ethernets:
ens160:
dhcp4: no
dhcp6:
no address: 192.168.10.13/24 gateway4:192.168.10.1
nameservers:
addresses: 142.55.100.25
142.55.44.25
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `ip route add` or `ip r a`

First add your IP to the route table
`ip route add 192.168.10.100 dev ens160 proto static metric 100`

Then add the route via the gateway
`ip route add default via 192.168.10.1 dev ens160 proto static metric 100`

These changes will be temporary until a reboot. To make them persist, you will need to add the changes to your NIC. On CentOS/Rhel distributions, this can be found in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens160`

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with the `ifconfig` command? You could use `ip` as well.

`ip addr change 192.168.1.111/32 dev eth0`

You can do it via `ip addr del/ip addr add` as well.

Comment: Thank you instead of eth0 I should use ens160?

Comment: Looks like it .